# Composite pattern in java

Tags: java, composite

I'm working on a program right now that allows you to create shapes (square, rectangles and circles) you also have an option to create a compound shape by selecting already created shapes...I'm using two observers for the shapes. One for squares/rectangles and one for large circles and these observers list the reference points and sizes of the shapes. When a compound shape is created it should list the components in the square/rectangle frame if there are squares/rectangles in the compound shape.

I'm supposed to create the compound shape using composite pattern. So basically compound shapes and my circles, squares and rectangles need to be handled the same way

I have an array of objects called shapes, and compound shape is an object with an array of shapes in it.

My question is how can I check through the shapes array for an object of type compound shape and then check through the compound shapes array for an instance of rectangle or square?

Sorry for not including code but my program is somewhat large with a lot of classes

heres the methods I use to check for an instance of square or rectangle...these two methods are in two different classes. The shapes display in the right observer window when theyre just the simple shapes but the compound shapes dont display. If for example I had a shape list with 3 shapes...shape 1 is a large circle, shape 2 is a compound shape and shape 3 is a rectangle. And lets say the compound shape has 2 squares. Right now this would display the large circle and the rectangle but it wont display the compound shape components. I thought that once I got to the compoundShape, instanceof would look pick out an instanceof square or rectangle from the compundshape array

heres the compound shapes toString method

```
public String toString(){
    String output="";
    output += "Compound Shape: /n";
    for (int i = 0; i< numShapes; i++){
        output += shapes[i].toString();
    }
    return output;
}
```

heres the do method I use to look for an instance of square or rectangle

```
do {//squares rectangles
        currentShape = shapes.getShape();
        if (shapes.squareRectangleFinder())
            outputString1 += currentShape.toString();
    }while (shapes.next());
```

and heres the square finder method

```
public boolean squareRectangleFinder() {
    if ((shapes[currentShape] instanceof Square)||(shapes[currentShape] instanceof Rectangle)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment... consider that you should not be "checking through".  What behaviors or attributes do you need to abstract and make available through the Compound classes public interface? Or perhaps through a shared interface all shapes share.

Comment: You can use the `instanceof` operator to check if the element in the array is an instance of the *CompoundShape* class.

Comment: That is true, but probably not in the spirit of what the homework is trying to teach.

Comment: "I'm using two observers for the shapes. One for squares/rectangles and one for large circles" That is another point that sounds like a problem with you class design. The `squareRectangleFinder()` problem for example can be solved if you add a method `isRectangular()` to `Shape`. If that is an important property of all shapes, make it one for all. Or add a class `RectangularShape` which defines this property and subclass `Recangle` and `Square` from there.

Comment: After reading the Wikipedia article it is pretty clear to me that composite pattern is about NOT using `instanceof`. - You just have to implement the same functionality on a CompoundShape that you do on a normal one.

Comment: But how would I determine I compound shape has a rectangle or square in it?

Comment: You can add a `hasRectangle()` and `hasSquare()` to your Shape interface. Then implement it in the classes: Rectangle will return true on hasRectangle only and Square will return true on hasSquare. - Then the CompoundShape's `hasRectangle()` just calls it's children's `hasRectangle()` until a `true` is found then return true, false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what "composite pattern" should do. Accordint to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern):

> clients should ignore the difference between compositions of objects and individual objects

In my understanding it should be done like this (getters/setters, add/remove operations omitted):

```
interface Shape {
    public int getLeftmostCoordinate();
}

class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private int top;
    private int left;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public int getLeftmostCoordinate() {
        return left;
    }
}

class Circle implements Shape {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int r;

    public int getLeftmostCoordinate() {
        return x - r;
    }
}

class CompoundShape implements Shape {
    private Shape[] shapes;

    public int getLeftmostCoordinate() {
        int left = shapes[0].getLeftmostCoordinate();

        for (int i=1; i<shapes.length; i++) {
            int candidate = shapes[i].getLeftmostCoordinate();
            if (candidate < left) {
                left = candidate;
            }
        }

        return left;
    }
}
```

Comment: While what this answer says is true, it is not good object oriented practice, and almost certainly not what the homework assignment is trying to teach.   A shared interface implemented by all Shapes, Compound, Circle, or whatever should abstract away the need for this technique, which really should only be used in the presence of reflection for abstract meta-coding.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Definitely, but the question itself is misleading, he asks how to distinguish between the classes. After checking wikipedia, it is the complete opposite what compound pattern should do.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ How about this one?

Comment: I think that is the idea :-)

Comment: I edited my post to include pieces of the code that should be doing what I need here...Im really sorry if its not clear, but I have about 12 different classes and dont know how else to show what Im doing on here

Comment: @krissyj05 The main point here is that all the objects expose the same interface to the ouside world. As you can see the caller does not have to care bout whether it calls this method on a Rectangle, on a Square or on a CompoundShape. The implementation decides how to handle the request but the **interface** exposed to the outside world is the same. (Btw: `Shape` can also be an abstract class instead of an interface).